# wrong show text when selected item datagrid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

i use this code

```
txt_f1.Text = datagrid_customer.SelectedCells[1].Column.GetCellContent(datagrid_customer.SelectedItem).ToString();
```

but when i click any item

show me:

```
System.windows.controls.textblock
```

datagrid code

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="861,-30,-261,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Name="datagrid_customer"  
          SelectionChanged="datagrid_customer_SelectionChanged">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="کد محصول" Binding="{Binding MahID}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: What are you trying to access from your code behind? Do you want to get the `MahID`?

Comment: yes i want get mah id

Comment: @dhilmathy my datagrid have more item but i just need mah id

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get `MahID`, you should be able to get it from the `SelectedItem` itself. Like,

```
private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = sender as DataGrid;
    var mahId = (grid.SelectedItem as YourModel).MahID;
}
```